# Soldering paste or flux

Tags: soldering, flux

There are a number of materials on the market that help with soldering, prevent oxidation. someone says **flux**, someone says **soldering paste** also someone says flux and soldering paste are same.

Frankly, I'm confused.

I also bought 4 different products that I saw in the market. Some are creamy, some are completely liquid. I can use the cream ones in some way, when I pour the liquid ones on the circuit, it flows and gone. I do not know exactly where and how these products are used.

Please tell me where to use each product and what is the benefit.

These are fluxes and soldering pastes:

[image]

[SR 33 No Clean Flux: Liquid](https://www.direnc.net/sivi-flux-beyaz-025lt-soldex)

[ASR 41 Flux: Resinous and Liquid](https://www.direnc.net/soldex-sivi-flux-recineli-1lt)

[AMTECH: Creamy](https://www.direnc.net/amtech-nc-559-asm-flux-krem-100g)

Purine: creamy

in side photo

[image]

Comment: Have you read the various manufacturer's recommendations? Presumably you're using lead-free of some type. Also consider whether your circuits are sensitive to surface leakage.

Comment: There are a number of tutorial videos on YouTube that show proper use of flux, selection of flux type for the application, etc. I recommend watching how it is done before you try pouring random products over your circuit boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all for one purpose - to clean the surfaces to be soldered.

The paste / cream types tend to leave a visible residue which melts further on heating during the soldering process, also it can be helpful to further add paste by dipping the solder into the paste.

The liquid is applied and it tends to dry, just heat and solder away.

Take care to make sure the fluxes are for the task at hand - fluxes for electrical are less aggresive compared to those for plumbing.

Many solders supplied for electrical are already combined with their flux.